# HttpHostConnectException let Apache Stanbol Integration Tests fail

Tags: apache, maven, apache-stanbol

I tried to install the Stanbol version from branch ["release-0.12"](https://github.com/apache/stanbol/tree/release-0.12) from github.

On my system I have:

- Apache Maven 3.0.5
- Maven home: /usr/share/maven
- Java version: 1.7.0_55, vendor: Oracle Corporation
- Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre

When I start the command:

```
mvn install
```

I get the following error for the Apache Stanbol Integration Tests => [error-log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PEZ_BdOySGYkEDLbDTd6VRaxIKgoYmMLoBTsxTfJHLM/edit?usp=sharing)

The first lines of the error are:

```
06.08.2014 15:47:02.025 *INFO * [main] Setting org.osgi.service.http.port=8765
06.08.2014 15:47:02.026 *INFO * [main] Starting launcher ...
06.08.2014 15:47:02.030 *INFO * [main] HTTP server port: 8765
15:47:03,614  INFO StanbolTestBase:163 - Got HttpHostConnectException at
  http://localhost:8765/ - will retry
```

When I skiped the test I also got no response from the server... 
I already tried it with java-version 1.6, but there I got the error:

```
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed
  with message:
Java 7 or higher is required to compile this module
```

Has someone an idea what I made wrong (does it need some further software requirements)? Or how can I get the server running correctly?

Comment: I now downloaded the [trunk-version](https://github.com/apache/stanbol/tree/trunk) from github. With skipping the tests I succeded to get the server running!

Answer (score 1):

The integration test starts a Stanbol Server (actually the full launcher) in its own JVM. The tests waits for up to 180 seconds for this server to start. During that time the test resends some test requests to check if the server is up and running.

Based on the provided log this period starts at about "15:47" so the test should wait until about "15:50" before it gives up.

Because of the line

```
^C15:48:42,236  INFO StanbolTestBase:146 - Got 404 at http://localhost:8765/entityhub - will retry
```

in the log my guess is that the build process was manually canceled with `^C` before the server was fully started.

The server side logs of the test run are available at `target/launchdir/stanbol/logs/error.log`. If the integration tests do fail one will usually find the reason in this log file.